# IonicPro Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ionic-framework

When I use **$ git push ionic master** to push my project. I can't because this error appears

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score -1):

type "sudo" before the command to become the "super user" and have the correct permissions to use this command

Comment: This is one of the possible errors with you command, the other main one is that the repositoy you are trying to post to does not exist.

Comment: I use windows git bash

Comment: oh, have you tried it hough?

Comment: Try using ctrl-shift when clicking on icon to open as admin

Comment: yes I tried, when I type "sudo" before the command I found error **sudo: command not found**

Comment: Error `Permission denied (publickey)` has nothing with local permissions so `sudo` doesn't help and would only make things worse.